# Como preencher as tabelas da base de dados com os dados dos textbox

Tags: php, banco-de-dados

No ficheiro externo PHP tenho o seguinte código:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
     <?php

    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "isabelso_isabel";
    $password = "password";
    $dbname = "isabelso_db";

    $dbconn = mysql_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    mysql_select_db($dbname);

    if (isset($_POST['botao_registo']))
    {
        $name = $_POST['nome'];
        $nif = $_POST['nif'];

         $sql = ("INSERT INTO Paciente (nome, id_paciente ) VALUES ('".$nome."', ' ".$nif."')");

    if(mysql_query($query))
 {
echo "<script>alert('INSERTED SUCCESSFULLY');</script>";
}
else
 {
 echo "<script>alert('FAILED TO INSERT ".mysql_error()."');</script>";
        }    
     }
```

O nome da tabela é `Paciente` e os atributos são: `nome, id_paciente`

O nome das textbox são `nome, nif`.

já no outro tenho:

```
    <body>

    <?php
          include("user_insert.php");
    ?>    
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="post">
        <p style="font-size: 15px"> <font face= "Verdana">
            &nbsp Nome:<INPUT type="text" name="nome" size=50>
                &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp Data de Nascimento: <input type="date" name="bday" > <br><br>
            &nbsp NIF:<INPUT type="number" name="nif" size=10> &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp
            &nbsp Telem&oacute;vel:<INPUT type="number" name="telemovel" size=10> <br><br>
            &nbsp Email:<INPUT type="email" name="email" size=40><br><br>
            &nbsp Password:<INPUT type="password" name="senha" size=30><br><br>
            &nbsp Password:<INPUT type="password" name="senha" size=30><br><br>
            &nbsp Alergias/Doen&ccedil;as Conhecidas:<INPUT type="text" name="doenças" size=50> <br><br>
            &nbsp Observa&ccedil;&otilde;es:<br>&nbsp <textarea name="observacoes" rows="5" cols="90" maxlength="500"></textarea>
            </p></font>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br> 

   <div id="botao">
      <input type="submit" name="botao_registo" value="ENVIAR DADOS" class=botaoEnviar />
```

haverá algo de errado com o código PHP porque quando preencho as text box e carrego no botão para enviar para a base de dados dá o erro: "FAILED TO INSERT", query was empty.

Comment: Isabel, comece tirando os colchetes quando vc passa os nomes das colunas no seu SQL.

Comment: Após conseguir fazer funcionar, dê uma pesquisada sobre SQL Injection para aprender como proteger seu script contra  esse tipo de ataque. No momento esse código está vulnerável.

Comment: Já resolveu seu problema?

Comment: não, já editei o código e coloquei em cima, mas o erro continua a dar o mesmo.

Comment: Isabel, seria interessante colocar no `echo` também o `mysql_error()`, ficando da seguinte maneira: `echo "<script>alert('FAILED TO INSERT ".mysql_error()."');</script>";`

Comment: Eu tenho duas suspeitas ai, eu acho que ele não está concatenando sua variável, então tente printar o SQL que é gerado no final antes de inserir primeiro. Se for isso basta usar `INSERT INTO...... VALUES ('".$nome."', '".$nif."')`

Comment: E acrescentei a sugestão do Everson e do @KhaosDoctor e editei o código em cima e agora o erro diz que a query está vazia, por isso acrescentei o código de onde estou a escrever os dados, caso o problema esteja vir daí

Comment: Alguém sabe como resolver o problema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema é que a variável `$query` não existe. A variável que você quer inserir é a `$sql`, que contém a `query`. Além disso acredito que não é necessário colocar a `query` entre colchetes, isso vai gerar erro. Então ficaria assim:

```
... codigo anterior ...

$sql = "INSERT INTO Paciente (nome, id_paciente ) VALUES ('".$nome."', ' ".$nif."')"; // retirei os colchetes

        if(mysql_query($sql)) // aqui esta o erro

... resto do código ...
```